# Apple Cinema Display support for HDCP

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display, cinema-display, hdcp

[High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) (HDCP) was released in the mid-2000s, contemporaneous with the Apple Cinema Display line of external monitors:

- 23", 30" Apple Cinema Display
- 24", 27" Apple LED Cinema Display
- Apple Thunderbolt Display

Did any of the above monitors support HDCP?

Can a connected macOS system display be queried to determine if it supports HDCP?

This is relevant as many of the adapters needed to connect these monitors to a modern USB-C / Thunderbolt Mac have "HDCP on" and "HDCP off" versions of the same adapter. Which should be used?

How can you determine if an Apple external monitor supports HDCP?

Comment: 30" seems to have versions that do and do not support HDCP: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-30-cinema-display-hdcp-error.1749138/

Comment: Potentially encoded in the monitor's [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156493/how-to-get-monitor-edid-in-osx